# typeahead mostrar resultados

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tengo un `inputText` que quiero autocompletar con una lista de palabras que se leen de una tabla de una bd mediante **ajax** utilizando **typeahead.js**.

El problema que tengo es que aunque por ajax me llegan todos los resultados que contienen el texto del input, no se me muestran todos, a veces me muestra uno, otras dos...

El codigo de javascript es el siguiente:

```
$('#txtEmpresa .typeahead').typeahead({
      highlight: true,
      hint:false,
      minLength: 3,
    },
    {
      name: 'empresas',
      display: 'empresas',
      source: function(query, processSync, processAsync) {
                return $.ajax({
                    url: '../autocomplete_empresas',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {
                        query: query
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(empresas) {                        
                        return processAsync(empresas);
                    }
                });
            },
       templates: {
           header: '<h3 class="bg-dark bg-font-dark">Empresas</h3>',
            suggestion: function (data) {
                return '<p>'+ data.nombre + '</p>';
            }
        }
    }
```

En el navegador veo que por ajax me llegan 5 objetos y si pongo `suggestion:function(data){console.log}`  me muestra por ejemplo solo dos.

¿Alguien sabe porque puede ser?

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de los datos que te llegan por ajax?

Comment: Puedes utilizar el plugin: Bloodhound, mas comodo y obtiene los datos exactos, https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Comment: Los datos que llegan por ajax:array({id=1,nombre="msi"}{id=2,nombre="grupo msi}...);